# Django: How to calculate the initial value of a field from two other fields?

Tags: python, django

I would like to make the totals a calculated field from two other fields, but not sure how to obtain their data respectively. (I tried .value without any joy)

```
Class TestForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
       self.fields['total_price'].initial = self.fields['price'].??? * self.fields['quantity'].???
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're dealing with a bound form, you can use `**kwargs['instance']` to get the Model instance.

So your `__init__` method will be something like -

```
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
       instance = kwargs['instance']
       self.fields['total_price'].initial = instance.price * instance.quantity
```

If you're not dealing with a bound form then you you can get the initial value with `self.fields['price'].initial`

Answer (score -1):

Thee is also an option to do it in the views.....

old fashioned way....

But that's not a model form...

so Aidan's answer is better, but if you really wanna do custom stuff... the old fashioned way

```
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = TestForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            whatever = form.cleaned_data['whatever']
            #and you can update the data and make the form with the new data
            data = {'whatever': whatever,'etc.': etc}
            form=TestForm(data)

else:
    # An unbound form
    form = TestForm(initial={'whatever': whatever,'etc.': etc})
return render_to_response(template,{'form':forms},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```